# document class for l'IHÉS Journal

Tags: document-classes

Let me just mention that I don't know much about Latex, so please be patient with me.

I noticed that the .cls file uses for the journal "Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS" is `svjour.cls`. So I just used this example

```
\documentclass[publmath]{svjour}

\reversetheomheadings     

\usepackage{publmath}

\begin{document}
```

But I get the following error: `l.93 ... valid journal specified in option list}{}`.

I am so thankful if you would please help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The [`svjour.cls` class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/springer/svjour/stropt) does not provide a `publmath` class option. You need to provide a class option that exists, details of which are available under section **2 Initializing the class** in the [`svjour` user's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/springer/svjour/stropt/usrguide.pdf) (p 2-3).

Moreover, you'll have to add the [`publmath` package](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour/publmath/) to your repertoire, most likely by storing it in your `texmf-local` folder. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But honestly I don't see what I should do. Indeed I did what you said, i.e adding the publmath.sty but still does not work. Is there any way that I can fix the problem?

Comment: Moreover what is .clo file?

Comment: @user11112: If you put [`publmath.sty`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour/publmath/publmath.sty) and [`svpublmath.clo`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour/publmath/svpublmath.clo) in the same folder as your working file, then things should work, and it seems like you *can* use `\documentclass[publmath]{svjour}`, since that option includes `svpublmath.clo`. Report back.